# Error while instantiating go chaincode on the new IBM Blockchain Platform

Tags: ibm-cloud, hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I am following the official IBM documentation [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/blockchain/howto?topic=blockchain-ibp-console-build-network) .

It is working fine up until chaincode installation. But when i am trying to instantiate the chaincode I am getting the below error.

```
An error occurred during instantiation.

grpc payload is empty: error starting container: error starting container: Post http://localhost:2375/build?t=dev-jdoe-track-1.0-a9bb38bb67b2784055e024f91d0ebc8515db909bfa46b1668e9c1b93832dbbad: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "Error attaching: configured logging driver does not support reading "
```

I am developing chaincode in Go and it is mentioned in the official docs that Go is supported in the new IBM Blockchain Platform ([here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/blockchain?topic=blockchain-develop-vscode#develop-vscode-creating-a-project)).

What else could be wrong here?

Comment: Go chaincode/smart contract is supported on the IBM Blockchain Platform.  Have you raised a support ticket?  Does it instantiate OK on the VS Code extension?
Where did you see the error?  Have you checked the logs?

Comment: sorry there was an error in the chaincode- I fixed it, packaged into .csd again and was able to instantiate successfully.

Comment: now i am facing a different error while invoking the chaincode with private data collections from app via Node SDK. error is `" Error: Failed disseminating 1 out of 3 private dissemination plans,.protos.Proposal "` . can you help?

Comment: @Pool when your question changes this much - close (or self-answer) your original question, and then open a new question.  Just FYI!

Answer (score 0):

As the OP said:

> sorry there was an error in the chaincode - I fixed it, packaged into .csd again and was able to instantiate successfully.

I am answering the question in this way because in looking for an answer to the same question, I did not realize that a chaincode issue, could produce an error that 'sounds so different'.   I wouldn't have found the answer had I not read someone else solving it that way.